# How Should I Name My iSCSI Targets?

Tags: iscsi

Is there a standard or generally accepted way of naming iSCSI targets? If not a sole standard then maybe a few? Or, is it simply entirely up to the administrator to name them as they wish?

I'm quite open to recommendations and to hear what others have done. I'd hate to be a month down the road, only to end up with a face-palm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see [RFC 3721](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3721).